# Using CameraX in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, android-camerax

I am trying to figure out how to use CameraX (https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) with Xamarin.Android, C# & Visual Studio. I have found lots of stuff for using CameraX in non-Xamarin apps, but almost nothing for Xamarin.Android, and the small amount that I have found related to Xamarin was designed for Xamarin.Forms rather than Xamarin.Android. I have not found any good Xamarin.Android tutorials for Camera2 (https://developer.android.com/training/camera2), which CameraX is based on. Can anybody recommend any good sites, tutorials or examples for using CameraX in a Xamarin.Android app?

Comment: The libraries using camerax needs have been integrated into the xamarin, so you can use it according to the native android official document and just convert the Java to the C#.

Comment: The links on the pages in my original post go to (I believe) pages with Kotlin code. Where exactly are you referring to when you say "native android official document"? I think there are difference as far as what needs done and how to do it for Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio.

Comment: Because I can't find any document about using it in the xamarin, so you can learn how to use it in the native android with java and then convert it to C#.

Comment: "native android with java and then convert it to C#"

Answer (score 0):

For Camera2, check XZing (https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Maui)

For CameraX, the C# binding library does not seem to exist. You can create your own though.

Official binding lib for Camera2:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/tree/main/source/androidx.camera

Binding lib doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/971390/nuget-packages-references-for-camerax-previewview) is saying the bindings do exist and you can get them from a Nuget package by searching for `Xamarin.AndroidX.Camera.Lifecycle`. I can confirm that package does exist. It seems it's then up to you to translate the Java from the regular Android documentation into C#. I hope to come back and add more information or pointers after I also move to CameraX in my app, but I want to migrate to MAUI first.